# Make a condition that invokes debugger when signalled?

Tags: common-lisp

What I'm trying to do:
I want the functionality of `simple-error` in another error. I want this for these reasons:

- to be able to handle it in a separate clause of `handler-case`.
- to avoid specifying the message string over and over again...
- to have debugger invoked when the error occurs.

I'm sort of puzzled this doesn't happen naturally by default, never paid enough attention to this issue, but this is apparently how it functions... What I am able to do is to signal an error, which I can later handle with `handler-case` or `handler-bind`, but this is bad, because I don't always remember whether the function throws or not, and when it does throw, but I forget to handle it, the function just returns early, as if nothing happened. But if I resume to using `simple-error`, then my code starts looking like:

```
...
(signal "Container ~S has no key ~S~&" :container foo :key bar)
...
(signal "Container ~S has no key ~S~&" :container foo :key baz)
...
```

And so on, all over the place :/ Of course I can dedicate a variable for saving the message text and maybe have a macro to make it shorter, but this doesn't help really, because it only hides the actual clutter instead of solving the problem.

What I could do so far:

```
(define-condition missing-key (condition)
  ((key :initarg :key
        :accessor key-of)
   (container :initarg :container
              :accessor container-of))
  (:documentation
   "An error rised when a KEY is not in the CONTAINER"
   :report
   #'(lambda (condition stream)
       (unless *print-escape*
         (format stream "~&Container ~S has no key ~S"
                 (container-of condition)
                 (key-of condition))))))

(handler-bind
    ((missing-key
      #'(lambda (condition)
          (invoke-debugger condition))))
  (signal 'missing-key :key 'foo :container 'bar))
```

What happens, however is that reporting function never gets called... when the error is signalled, instead it prints a generic message `Condition MISSING-KEY was signalled.`

EDIT:

Thanks to sds answer, this is what I have now:

```
(define-condition missing-key (error)
  ((key :initarg :key
        :accessor key-of)
   (container :initarg :container
              :accessor container-of))
  (:documentation
   "An error rised when a KEY is not in the CONTAINER")
  (:report
   (lambda (condition stream)
     (format stream "Container ~S has no key ~S"
             (container-of condition)
             (key-of condition)))))

(defmacro signal-missing-key (container key)
  `(let ((*break-on-signals*
          (cond
            ((null *break-on-signals*) 'missing-key)
            ((consp *break-on-signals*)
             (list 'or 'missing-key (cdr *break-on-signals*)))
            (t (list 'or *break-on-signals* 'missing-key)))))
     (signal 'missing-key :key ,container :container ,key)))
```

I could probably make it more generic by passing more arguments down to `signal`, but this does what I wanted to do initially, so, unless there is a better way to do the same thing, I'll probably just use this.

Comment: I didn't read your question closely, but couldn't you just set [`*break-on-signals*`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/v_break_.htm) to the type of your condition to make it enter the debugger when signalled?

Comment: Well, that's the first thing that came to my mind when skimming your question. This being Lisp, there surely are other ways to achieve what you want, but I don't know an easier one off the top of my head.

Comment: Looking at this question again, I think I don't really understand. Why do you need the macro above and what's keeping you from just setting `*break-on-signals*` to `simple-error` (or even `t` if you want that for every unhandled condition)? If you want to get really fancy about that, you could even define a new type that checks a slot `breaks` or something in your condition so that the debugger is only entered in cases where you signal with `:breaks t`. I somehow fail to see the problem. (Or do you need example code for something like that?)

Comment: As far as I can tell, usually `error` or `cerror` (which you can also use with your own condition types, not only descendants of `error` or `simple-error`) are used instead of `signal`to get the behavior you want. So yes, it's used a bit differently than in other languages. I see your point, but it's not really that much hassle to set `*break-on-signals*` to `error` to get the behavior you want for all error conditions, even when just `signal`led.

Comment: Ok, I'll make it an answer then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`error`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_error.htm) or [`cerror`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_cerror.htm) with your own condition types, if you want the debugger to be invoked unless the conditions are handled otherwise. This also works for conditions that are not descendants of [`simple-error`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/e_smp_er.htm).

If you want this behavior for [`signal`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_signal.htm#signal), too, you can set the variable [`*break-on-signals*`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/v_break_.htm) to the according type. For example, you could set it to `t` in order to invoke the debugger for *every* unhandled condition.

Answer (score 2):

Your code works as you intended with the following modifications: remove `#'` before `lambda`, remove `~&` from `format` (error reporting does that and more), close the `:documentation` clause and open the `:report` clause:

```
(define-condition missing-key (condition)
  ((key :initarg :key
        :accessor key-of)
   (container :initarg :container
              :accessor container-of))
  (:documentation
   "An error rised when a KEY is not in the CONTAINER")
  (:report
   (lambda (condition stream)
       (unless *print-escape*
         (format stream "Container ~S has no key ~S"
                 (container-of condition)
                 (key-of condition))))))
MISSING-KEY
(signal 'missing-key :key 'foo :container 'bar)
==> NIL
(handler-bind
    ((missing-key
      #'(lambda (condition)
          (invoke-debugger condition))))
  (signal 'missing-key :key 'foo :container 'bar))


*** - Container BAR has no key FOO
The following restarts are available:
ABORT          :R1      Abort main loop
Break 1 [46]>
```

i.e., `signal` prints nothing but `handler` invokes the debugger.

Comment: Then you need to inherit from `simple-error` (or `error` or `cerror` if you want to be able to continue) instead of `condition`.

Answer (score 1):

Make your condition a subclass of `ERROR` rather than `CONDITION`. Not all conditions are errors that require intervention via debugger, and the condition class hierarchy is designed to distinguish between them.